# Como cambiar el contenido de un contenedor por hipervinculos

Tags: html

Tengo un wrapper con botones y un contenedor a la derecha, mi idea es que cuando presiono uno de los botones del wrapper el href no me redirija a otra página sino que muestre un div el id correspondiente. El problema que tengo es que se me ponen los div uno debajo del otro y a la hora de presionar el boton hace efecto scroll, es decir, baja a donde esta el contenido de ese div. yo lo que quiero es que muestre solo uno y al presionar se cambie por el otro.

Este es mi código:

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-heading">Panel de usuario </div>
  <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <a href="#Shop" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Tienda</a>
    <a href="#Profile" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Perfil</a>
    <a href="#Contact" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Contacta</a>
  </div>
</div>
  
<!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Menu</button>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="../index.html">Inicio <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">       
          <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>    
  </nav>
<div>
    <div id="Shop">
          <img src="../img/carlos1.png" alt="">

    </div>
    <div id="Contact">

          <img src="../img/carlos2.png" alt="">
    </div>    
</div>
</div>
  
<!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
```

En este código lo que busco es que al presionar una de las opciones del sidebar muestre las imagenes de los div de abajo. Solo debería mostrar uno y en el caso de que presione sobre el boton tienda o contacta. Pero a mi me muestra una debajo de otra y al presionar el boton hace scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo muy bien tu código, pero si entiendo la idea de lo quieres hacer (o al menos eso creo). Así que te voy a poner un ejemplo y luego tu lo adaptas a como lo necesites.

**Contexto:**

Tengo un `div` llamado `"vista"`, y dos botones. Dependiendo de que botón presione el usuario `"vista"` va a tener cierto(s) elementos. Entonces, voy añadir el evento `onclick` a los dos botones, cada evento invoca una función diferente. Esta función hace un `innerHTML` sobre el `div` `"vista"`:

```
<button onclick="ver1()">Opcion 1</button>
<button onclick="ver2()">Opcion 2</button>
<div id="vista"></div>
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Obviamente** cargo el script al final del body, para que se carguen primero todos los elementos (botones y contenedor). Así me ahorro los problemas que suelen generar los eventos.

Hecho esto, en la página se ve algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, como dependo de `innerHTML` para que `"vista"` se dinámico voy a definir las funciones en Javascript:

```
const vista = document.getElementById("vista")

function ver1() {
    vista.innerHTML = //Aquí añadí una imagen de internet
}

function ver1() {
    vista.innerHTML = //Y aquí los lyrics de Skys The Limit de Biggie Smalls
}
```

**Nota:** Puse comentarios para describir lo que puse en cada `innerHTML`, ya que los lyrics completos son largos y el link de la imagen también.

**Resultados:**

Finalmente, veamos la página cuando presiono el botón que dice "opcion 1":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando presiono el botón que dice "opcion 2":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si me haya explicado claramente, pero al menos espero que sirva de algo (**no dudes en corregirme si no te entendí bien**). Saludos!

Comment: Si entiendo la forma en que lo haces pero la veo bastante compleja, yo se que hay una forma de con una navbar segun presiono en los hipervinculos <a> cambiaba el contenido si lo ponias dentro de un div en concreto. La forma que me dices me funciona perfecto pero la veo mas dificil que la otra.

Comment: Tu investigación no ha tenido resultados? Es que nunca había escuchado esa manera. xDD

Comment: No aún no, pero en su momento lo hice, cuando empeze a toquetear html hice un navbar que me cambiaba de div en vez de hacer scroll, era en un container-fill de bootstrap 4

Comment: Este codigo fue el que hice, es muy sencillo pero funcionaba de la forma que quiero, aunque no se el porque. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q1mVhsEbXlfMitUK97fDoDjh1ViUyhKj/view?usp=sharing